# Using flatMap with a Completable

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I am trying to make an API call multiple times, passing in a different parameter. When no more data is returned, the rx stream should terminate. After each call, the data is stored in my local repository. Here is what I have:

```
val startPositions = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0)

startPositions.flatMap { startPos -> App.context.repository.getConnections(startPos) }
        .flatMap { connections -> App.context.repository.storeConnections(connections) }
        .doOnNext { startPos -> startPositions.onNext(startPos + 1) }
        .subscribe({ startPos -> println("Index $startPos") })
```

Here is the api method to handle downloading the data:

```
 override fun getConnections(startPos: Int): Observable<List<Connection>> {
            return myAPI.getConnections(startPos)
        }
```

And this is the api method for storing the data:

```
override fun storeConnections(connections: List<Connection>): Completable =
        Completable.fromAction {
            appDao.storeConnections(connections.map {
                mapper.toDb(it)
            })
        }
```

The compile error I get is:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is (List) -> Completable but ((List) -> ObservableSource!)! was expected

If possible, I don't want to change the return types of my api calls. I'm also not certain about using a flatMap. The data returned from downloading is a list and I want the list to remain as a list in the stream. I don't want to emit individual list items.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the type mismatch error, use operator `flatMapCompletable` instead of `flatMap`:

```
    .flatMapCompletable { connections -> App.context.repository.storeConnections(connections) }
```

Then you will have to use `doOnComplete` instead of `doOnNext`:

```
    .doOnComplete { startPos -> startPositions.onNext(startPos + 1) }
```